# Mysql Cumulative Sum grouped by name and date

Tags: mysql, group-by, common-table-expression, cumulative-sum

I had a task, in which I should cumulate two different Dates, which I did with the following query:

```
with cte as (
select p.starteddate as CD,
(select count(*) from TABLE t1 where p.starteddate=t1.starteddate) Started,
(select count(*) from TABLE t1 where p.starteddate=t1.updateddate) Updated
from TABLE p
group by CD, Started, Updated
)
select
 CD,
  sum(Started) over (order by CD asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Started,
  sum(Updated) over (order by CD asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Updated
from cte
order by CD desc;
```

Now, I have to put more values in that query, where I am stuck.

1. The query should take the Names into consideration and only cumulate the dates by each name. Since there are 11 names or so, I guess the best option would be to retrieve the names first with a distinct query, but I do not have an idea how to go further here.
2. Only Type A should be taken into consideration
3. Also since there are 1000 rows and counting and the dates are going back to one year, only the last 60 days should be taken into consideration.

Thanks!
[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFwsH.png)

| Type | Startdate | updateddate | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12/01/21 | 12/01/21 | D |
| A | 11/01/21 | 12/01/21 | D |
| A | 13/01/21 | 13/01/21 | E |
| A | … | … | . |
| A | 07/01/21 | 11/01/21 | E |
| A | 12/01/21 | 14/01/21 | E |
| A | … | … | . |
| A | 14/01/21 | 14/01/21 | G |
| A | 12/01/21 | 12/01/21 | D |
| A | 11/01/21 | 12/01/21 | D |
| A | 13/01/21 | 13/01/21 | E |
| A | … | … | . |
| A | 07/01/21 | 11/01/21 | E |
| A | 12/01/21 | 14/01/21 | E |
| A | 14/01/21 | null | G |
| A | 11/01/21 | 11/01/21 | F |
| A | 14/01/21 | 15/01/21 | G |

[Expected Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts8z2.png)

| Name | Date | Count Start | Count Updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | 07/01/21 | 2 | 0 |
| E | 11/01/21 | 2 | 2 |
| E | 12/01/21 | 4 | 2 |
| E | 13/01/21 | 6 | 4 |
| D | 11/01/21 | 2 | 0 |
| D | 12/01/21 | 4 | 4 |
| G | 14/01/21 | 3 | 1 |
| G | 15/01/21 | 3 | 2 |
| F | 11/01/21 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome as text , which we can use, rather than linked images which we can't.

Comment: Fair point, I edited it with the only relevant A Type

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following which :

1. Performs a union on the dataset to ensure all dates are considered. Within the first CTE `t1` which creates this union we apply your filter by `Type` and last 60 days using `date >= (CURRENT_DATE-interval 60 day)` *(this has been commented out for this example)*
2. With all possible dates, CTE `t2` performs the counts before
3. finding the cumulative sum of the counts in the last projection using window function `SUM`

```sql
    WITH t1 as (
        SELECT
            name,
            startdate as `date`,
            'start' as datetype
        FROM
            my_table
        WHERE
            Type='A' -- AND startdate >= (CURRENT_DATE-interval 60 day)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            name,
            updateddate as `date`,
            'updated' as datetype
        FROM
            my_table
        WHERE
            Type='A' -- AND updateddate >= (CURRENT_DATE-interval 60 day)
    ),
    t2 as (
        SELECT 
            name,
            `date`,
            COUNT(
               CASE
                   WHEN datetype='start' THEN 1 
               END
            ) as cstart,
            COUNT(
               CASE
                   WHEN datetype='updated' THEN 1 
               END
            ) as cend
         FROM
             t1
         WHERE `date` IS NOT NULL
         GROUP BY
             name,
             `date`
     )
    SELECT
        name as `Name`,
        `date` as `Date`,
        SUM(cstart) OVER (
            PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY `date`
        ) as `Count Start`,
        SUM(cend) OVER (
            PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY `date`
        )  as `Count Updated`
    FROM
       t2
    ORDER BY
       name, `date`;
```

| Name | Date | Count Start | Count Updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D | 2021-01-11 | 2 | 0 |
| D | 2021-01-12 | 4 | 4 |
| E | 2021-01-07 | 2 | 0 |
| E | 2021-01-11 | 2 | 2 |
| E | 2021-01-12 | 4 | 2 |
| E | 2021-01-13 | 6 | 4 |
| E | 2021-01-14 | 6 | 6 |
| F | 2021-01-11 | 1 | 1 |
| G | 2021-01-14 | 3 | 1 |
| G | 2021-01-15 | 3 | 2 |

---

[View working demo online on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iZBaCTShjtnEFCQtZQvzB4/1)

Comment: Wow. Thank you! That is exactly what I intended to do. I just validated the values and it works like supposed to. Now I will look into the code more closely. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I just figured, that the output needs to be adapted a little. I will edit my questions with the output of your table.